# Why child route won't render without the parent route rendering?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to navigate to `/movie/:title` on which I am rendering a new page. But it only renders if my movie page i.e `/movie renders`, but I don't want my movie page to be mounted on navigating to `/movie/:title`. I only want it as part of the path. Making the `/movie` path exact doesn't work as `/movie/:title` wouldn't render with `/movie` as exact.

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <div>
      <Header />
      <Route path='/movies' component={Movies} />
      <Route path='/tvshows' component={TvShow} />      
   </div>
)}
```

Movie.js

```
return (
   <div className="movies">
        <Route path={`${match.path}`} render={(props) => <CollectionGrid movies/>} />
        <Route path={`${match.path}`} render={(props) => <CollectionOverview movies/>} />
        <Route path={`${match.path}/:title`} component={ItemPage} />
   </div>
);
```

Comment: Hi Shivam, please see my solution below and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of notes. Conventionally, you should keep all your routes in a single router, thus making it easier to navigate and identify your application.

Organize your Router like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Movies from "./Movies";
import ItemPage from "./ItemPage";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
          <Route path="/movies/:title" component={ItemPage} />
          <Route path="/movies" component={Movies} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Additionally, to resolve your solution, you would need the `Switch` component, which is available in `react-router-dom`. The `Switch` component, will look through a list of `Routes` and will only **render the FIRST `Route` who's `path` string is included within the URL string**.

In the list above we have 3 Routes. If your URL is `"/movies/blah"`, it will only render the `ItemPage` component, because that Route's `path` was matched first within the list.

We moved the `"/movies/:title"` Route before the regular `"/movies"` for this very reason. If the `"/movies"` Route appeared first in the list and if your URL was `"/movies/blah"`, it would still satisfy the `"/movies"` Route. That means Switch would only render `Movies` component, which is not what you want.

See working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-bogdan-lzl76

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks. May I ask what work is switch doing here?

Comment: You're welcome! I can edit my answer, to explain more in-depth on what the Switch is doing :)

Comment: @ShivamAima cool let me know if that makes more sense. Please consider upvoting and marking this as the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

you are not able to access to match  direct  in this app the match is found in `this .props.match`
you cand used it in

```
const App({match})
```

then when you need to used it should

```
<Route path={`${match.path}`} render={(props) => <CollectionGrid movies/>} />
```

[look to this example and explain](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/hitchhikers-guide-to-react-router-v4-4b12e369d10/)